# RewriteRule not working 301 redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule packersandmovers/(.*)/$ http://comparelogistic.in/packersandmovers/city/$1
```

Above is my code for redirecting page

- http://exmaple.com/query

to

- http://exmaple.com/city/query

but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working and what url are you going to?

Comment: You need to use R flag for the RewriteRule - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r

Answer (score 0):

Put the follwoing code @ query directory :

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exmaple.com/city/query/$1  [L,R=301]
```

So any page @ http://exmaple.com/query/ will be directory to http://exmaple.com/city/query with same extensions